# Irony: How to disallow a space between 2 tokens?

Tags: c#, grammar, irony

I'm trying to define PHP-style variables in [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) like so:

```
variable.Rule = "$" + identifier;
```

Works great, except that you're allowed to put spaces between the `$` and the `identifier`. I want to prevent that. How?

Do I have to create a new customized terminal? If so, will I still be able to take advantage of the `IdentifierTerminal` magic?

---

Digging around in `IdentifierTerminal` I see there's actually a flag for "NameIncludesPrefix", but it's only used in one place. Looks like the prefix is stored in this `CompoundTokenDetails` object... which I'm not sure how to use. **Edit:** Nevermind, this was a dead-end. Those flags are for adding modifiers to how the variable behaves.

---

This kinda works...

```
class VariableTerminal : Terminal
{
    public VariableTerminal(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }

    public override IList<string> GetFirsts()
    {
        return new[] { "$" };
    }

    public override Token TryMatch(ParsingContext context, ISourceStream source)
    {
        if (source.PreviewChar != '$') return null;
        do
        {
            source.PreviewPosition++;
        } while (!source.EOF() && char.IsLetter(source.PreviewChar));

        var token = source.CreateToken(OutputTerminal);
        return token;
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure what `OuputTerminal` is though.. I guess it's some kind of dynamic property based on the current preview position? The way parsing is done in Irony is a little strange I think...

Anyway, the problem with this is what when I use this `VariableTerminal`, instead of how I was doing it before with `"$" + IdentifierTerminal"`, when there's a syntax error, such as in this code:

```
p cat
```

The identifier terminal used to say

> Syntax error, expected: { real string $ true false ...

But the variable gives me this error instead:

> Invalid character: 'c'

The former error was more useful I think. I don't really understand why it's spitting out a different error...how can I get it to say that instead?

Comment: (I've been trying to think of a "How ironic!" joke since when I saw this but haven't thought of any...)

Answer (score 6):

for me it looks clear that what you want is currently not supported (checked in the sources). See the discussion on the [pascal character](http://irony.codeplex.com/discussions/70460) (the very botoom) as well which is identified as '#number' not allowing space between.

To go with non-terminal is not a way I believe. Grammars work by nature that you can have whitespaces between tokens. So what you really need is to follow advice given on the [project wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Irony_-_Language_Implementation_Kit/Grammar/Terminals) - section **Custom Terminals** on the bottom of the page and extend the Terminal class to fit your needs.

Or the easiest option would be to introduce flag which can make the prefix mandatory. Extending the `IdentifierTerminal` class and overriding `TryMatch` method.

If you look on this method in `CompoundTerminalBase` class what the `TryMatch` method does is basically:

1. ReadPrefix (but more less ignore if the prefix was found or not)
2. ReadBody (fails if the body wasn't read)
3. ReadSuffix

The `ReadPrefix` method sets a `details.Prefix` flag if a prefix is found. So after calling `ReadPrefix` you may want to check your newly introduced flag for mandatory prefix and if it is set you can check if the `details.Prefix` flag is set as well, otherwise you emit an error.

Good luck :)

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I'll give you the +250 before it expires. Looks good.

Comment: Let me know how it went, epsecially if you didn't figure this out.

Comment: Getting close... see my question update? Maybe you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know wich version of Irony you use, but with the current version I was able to get that working using AllFirstChars:

```
        var localVariable = new IdentifierTerminal(NodeType.LocalVariable);
        localVariable.AllFirstChars = "$";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hrm...maybe that's new. Don't remember seeing that. Will have to try that if I ever come back to this project.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this one might help:

http://irony.codeplex.com/discussions/70460

So, sharing it for the 2 lines:

```
  var identifier = new IdentifierTerminal("Identifier", IdFlags.NameIncludesPrefix);
  identifier.AddPrefix(Strings.AllLatinLetters, IdFlags.None);   //[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9])
```

I think you won't be using them in the same way exactly, but maybe something similar.

Comment: Nope. The prefix is still optional. I want it to be required.

Answer (score 0):

```
var identifier = new IdentifierTerminal("identifier", IdFlags.NameIncludesPrefix);
identifier.AddPrefix("$", IdFlags.None);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: That's almost letter for letter what Mohammed said... that doesn't do what it looks like it does.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jan that this should be handled in the scanner, not in the parser.

Does including '$' in extraFirstChars do what you want?

```
public IdentifierTerminal(string name, string extraChars, string extraFirstChars)
```